# Conditionally rename data frame columns in a list depending on position in list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of 216 data frames, each with 3 variables. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B= 11:20, C = 21:30)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 31:40, B = 41:50, C = 51:60) 
listDF <- list(df1, df2)
```

I need to rename the variables in each data frame sequentially depending on its location in the list. That I can do. For example:

```
#create lists of the variable names
Bnames <- c("feel1", "feel2")
Cnames <- c("cat1", "cat2")
#sequentially name each data frame's columns
k <- 0
for(i in 1:length(listDF)){
  k = k+1
  names(listDF[[i]]) <- c("ID",Bnames[k],Cnames[k])
  }
#I know people prefer lapply; I tend to switch back and forth depending on what I'm doing
```

The problem I'm having is that in the list of 216 data frames (24 "cat" variables x 9 "feel" variables = 216), I need the lists of 'Bnames' and 'Cnames' to sequence at different rates. I need the first 9 data frames to have C = cat1, with B = feel1:9, the next 9 to have C = cat2, with B = feel1:9, and so on. So I need to recursively sequence along B, but slowly sequence along C every 9 data frames. 'A' should be "ID" in every data frame.

I'm really at a loss for how to do this. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Also -- if anyone has a suggestion for a more understandable title, I'll gladly change it.

**EDIT:**

It might help to know where I want to end up when I'm done. Each ID is present in a differing number of the dataframes, and ultimately what I want is to reshape and merge the data frames into 1 data frame with the following format:

```
ID  feel1.1  feel1.2 ... feel2.1   feel2.2
2   NA       4           NA        7
3   2        1           6         3
```

Where feel1.1 indicates the "feel1" value for "cat1" and there are missing values if an ID did not have a particular combination of "feel" and "cat" (so ID 2 did not have a feel1 value for cat1 but did for cat2. Ultimately, there should be 217 columns and as many rows as there are IDs.

**My (bad) solution:**

```
X <- listDF
#create lists of the data frame numbers for each "feel" variable
feel1 <- seq(1,216,by=9)
feel2 <- seq(2,216,by=9)
feel3 <- seq(3,216,by=9)
feel4 <- seq(4,216,by=9)
feel5 <- seq(5,216,by=9)
feel6 <- seq(6,216,by=9)
feel7 <- seq(7,216,by=9)
feel8 <- seq(8,216,by=9)
feel9 <- seq(9,216,by=9)

#assign correct names for the "feel" variables in each data frame
for(i in 1:length(X)){
  if(i %in% feel1){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel1")
  }
  if(i %in% feel2){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel2")
  }
  if(i %in% feel3){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel3")
  }
  if(i %in% feel4){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel4")
  }
  if(i %in% feel5){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel5")
  }
  if(i %in% feel6){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel6")
  }
  if(i %in% feel7){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel7")
  }
  if(i %in% feel8){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel8")
  }
  if(i %in% feel9){
    names(X[[i]]) <- c("UniqueID", "cat", "feel9")
  }
}

#'melt' each of the dataframes and then remove the rows with 'cat'
X <- lapply(X, function(x) melt(x, id.vars ="UniqueID"))
X <- lapply(X, function(x) subset(x, variable != "cat"))

#add the appropriate 'cat' number to each 'feel' name
for(j in 1:length(X)){
  if(j <= 9){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".24")
  }
  if(j > 9 & j <= 18){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".1")
  }
  if(j > 18 & j <= 27){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".2")
  }
  if(j > 27 & j <= 36){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".3")
  }
  if(j > 36 & j <= 45){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".4")
  }
  if(j > 45 & j <= 54){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".5")
  }
  if(j > 54 & j <= 63){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".6")
  }
  if(j > 63 & j <= 72){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".7")
  }
  if(j > 72 & j <= 81){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".8")
  }
  if(j > 81 & j <= 90){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".9")
  }
  if(j > 90 & j <= 99){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".10")
  }
  if(j > 99 & j <= 108){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".11")
  }
  if(j > 108 & j <= 117){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".12")
  }
  if(j > 117 & j <= 126){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".13")
  }
  if(j > 126 & j <= 135){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".14")
  }
  if(j > 135 & j <= 144){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".15")
  }
  if(j > 144 & j <= 153){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".16")
  }
  if(j > 153 & j <= 162){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".17")
  }
  if(j > 162 & j <= 171){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".18")
  }
  if(j > 171 & j <= 180){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".19")
  }
  if(j > 180 & j <= 189){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".20")
  }
  if(j > 189 & j <= 198){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".21")
  }
  if(j > 198 & j <= 207){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".22")
  }
  if(j > 207 & j <= 216){
    X[[j]]$variable <- paste0(X[[j]]$variable, ".23")
  }
}

#reshape each data frame into 2 columns: ID and the renamed 'feel' variable
X <- lapply(X, function(x) dcast(x, UniqueID ~ variable))

#merge it back onto the original dataset
for(i in 1:length(X)){
  data <- merge(data, X[[i]], by="UniqueID", all=T)
}
```

Comment: You can do `library(data.table); rbindlist(dfList, idcol = TRUE)` which will stack your data and make a column called `.id` based on order within the list. From there, you can condition on `.id` (and maybe don't need to rename anything).

Answer (score 0):

I would combine them all together with a list element variable, and change from long to wide format. Now you just have to change 1 set of variable names as a list of strings (or a string vector, I'm not sure exactly) instead of many name lists inside list elements.

```
# sample data
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B= 11:20, C = 21:30)
df2 <- data.frame(A = 5:14, B = 41:50, C = 51:60) 
listDF <- list(df1, df2)

require(reshape)
require(plyr)

# put them all in 1 long dataframe
df <- rbind.fill(listDF)

# label which list element they came from and pretty up the vars
df$listnum <- rep((1:length(listDF)),times = lapply(listDF,nrow))
names(df) <- c('id','cat','feel','listnum')

# change from long to wide
df <- reshape(df,idvar = 'id',timevar = 'listnum',direction = 'wide')
```

I'm not exactly sure how you are naming your variables, but the result of the above has all the information you need in it. You'll just need to do `names(df) <- sub()` a bit. And to cycle at different rates, just let R recycle the shorter vector. Something like:

```
paste(rep(1:24,each = 9),1:9,sep = '.')
```